# Parsing int from the start of a byte[] from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, arrays

I have a Java application that is reading data from a TCP socket that is receiving XML of varying size. The first 5 bytes of a given packet are supposed to indicate the size of the remaining message. I can read the message and xml successfully if I manually create a large byte[] and read the data.

Here are the instructions from the manual for the application that is generating the data:

> Each message is preceded by the message size indicator which is a
>   32-bit unsinged integer using the network bytes order method. For
>   example: \x05\x00\x00\x00\x30\x31\x30\x32\x00 indicates the message
>   size of an ack which is 5 bytes included the fifth message byte '\0'. The
>   size indicator specifies everything following the size indicator
>   itself.

However I can't figure out how to decode the first 5 bytes to an integer that I can use to correctly size a byte[] for reading the rest of the message. I get random results:

Here is the code I'm using to parse the message:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedInputStream inFromServer = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

byte[] data = new byte[10];
inFromServer.read(data);
String result = new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");

Logger.info(data+"");

//PROBLEM AREA: Tried reading different byte lengths but no joy
//This should be a number but it never is. Often strange symbols
byte[] numeric = Arrays.copyOfRange(data,1,5);
String numericString = new String(numeric, "ISO-8859-1");

//Create a huge array to make sure everything gets captured. 
//Want to use the parsed value from the start here
byte[] message = new byte[1000000];
inFromServer.read(message);

//This works as expected and returns correctly formatted XML
String fullMessage = new String(message, "ISO-8859-1");

Logger.info("Result "+result+ " Full message "+fullMessage);
```

Comment: the message length is in the first four not five bytes

Comment: that "network bytes order" looks suspiciously like little-endian, also known as *not* network byte order.

Comment: The instructions are incorrect. That isn't 5 in network byte order. If it was, you could use `DataInputStream.readInt()`. As it is, you should complain to the vendor ('seek clarification'). And this isn't XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length looks like it's little endian.  You can still use DataInputStream but you have to swap the bytes. If you used NIO's SocketChannel and a ByteBuffer you could set the byte order, but this is likely to be harder to use.

```
// only do this once per socket.
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                                  new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

// for each message.
int len0 = in.readInt();
int len = Integer.reverseBytes(len0);
assert len < 1 << 24;

byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
in.readFully(bytes);

String text = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1").trim();
int number = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

Comment: This is correct as it relates to the documentation posted in the question. However it, t urns out the documentation is wrong in the other way though. The example is little endian in the doc but the data is coming down big endian.

Comment: @JoeW in that case, you can drop the `reverseBytes`

Answer (score 2):

Network byte order is aka [big-endian](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Endianness). But seeing your data it seems, that actually little-endian is used. At least `5` will look like those first 4 bytes in little-endian, but not in big-endian. So you need to read those bytes, consider little-endian and convert to long to consider "unsigned-ness".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(null));

    int iSize = inFromServer.readInt();
    iSize = Integer.reverseBytes(iSize); //read as little-endian

    long count = Integer.toUnsignedLong(iSize); //unsigned int
}
```

Comment: 'Network byte order' is defined in an RFC as big-endian.